# React - props should be defined as false

Tags: reactjs, state

Working in React and I need to define props state to false.
Right now I have my state set like this and it works:

```
this.state = {
  XXS: false,
  XS: false,
  S: false,
  SM: false,
  M: false,
  L: false,
  XL: false,
  XXL: false,
};
```

But I need it little more simple than that as there might be more sizes in the future so they shouldn't be hard coded. Is there any one liner I could use for this?

Something in a form of:

```
this.state.sizes = false;
```

Thanks you for any input!

Comment: You mention props, but, your code uses state. Neither are particularly related to your problem, which sounds like a data organisation or object structuring one. Can you elaborate on your exact problem? Sounds like a helper function which changes all state items to its input parameter would be a good starting point but its unclear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't very clear. Anyway, I've solved it and post it. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Use `setState` like this:

```
for(var propertyName in this.state) {
    this.setState({ [propertyName]: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was too easy...

```
this.state = {
  sizes: false
};
```

Comment: Be careful, according to [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) you should not mutate `this.state` directly.